# Does Swift have an “or equals” function like ||= in Ruby?

Tags: swift, null-coalescing-operator

In Swift, how do I set an optional `foo` but only if it's `nil`?

I know about [Swift's nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72):

`foo = foo ?? "Hello"` (where `foo` is an optional `String`)

But, is there a better way, like in Ruby?

`foo ||= "Hello"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such an operator was considered and rejected. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0024-optional-value-setter.md).

The rationale behind the rejection is supposed to be in the swift-evolution email list, but the link attached to the above points to SE-0025 instead of 24.

---

The the original rationale is now at [gmane.io](https://admin.gmane.io). You can request access to the mailing list by searching for the "gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution" group (partial credit to the user from the comments).

Comment: Ok what the... in that thread, there isn't a single reviewer who isn't in favour of adopting it. Curious why the proposal is marked rejected?

Comment: After reading some of the reviews, it seems the final analysis was that since it doesn't make the var non-optional (the ?? op returns a non-optional,) it would have very limited usefulness. That makes sense to me.

Comment: Actually I believe this is the [link to the rationale](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution/7694) that was posted.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, that's the way to do it. If you want you can wrap it up in your own operator:

```
infix operator ||= {}
func ||=<T>(inout left: Optional<T>, right: T) { left = left ?? right }

var foo:String? = nil // foo -> nil
foo ||= "Hello"       // foo -> "Hello"
foo ||= "Hi"          // foo -> "Hello"
```

I'd recommend using `??=` to match the pattern `foo = foo ?? "Hello"` but use whatever feels comfortable to you.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 5.1**

```
infix operator ||=
func ||=<T>(lhs: inout Optional<T>, rhs: @autoclosure () -> T) { lhs = lhs ?? rhs() }

var foo:String? = nil // foo -> nil
foo ||= "Hello"       // foo -> "Hello"
foo ||= "Hi"          // foo -> "Hello"
```

See here for the reason why `@autoclosure` is important: https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/10/implementing-rubys-operator-in-swift/

Comment: Why is this not a static function?

Answer (score 0):

For `Bool` types in Swift 3:

```
infix operator ||=
func ||=(lhs: inout Bool, rhs: Bool) { lhs = (lhs || rhs) }
```

Usage:

```
var bool = false
bool ||= false // false
bool ||= true // true
bool ||= false // true
```